# Garbage disposal hums but won't spin

Tags: kitchens, sink, garbage-disposal

I moved in to a new house a few months ago and the other day I noticed my garbage disposal stopped working. The unit is an Insinkerator Badger 1 with 1/3 HP. When I flip the switch I can hear the unit humming, but nothing happens. The reset button is not out (although I did try pressing it anyway just for fun). The unit plugs in to an outlet under the sink, so I did plug something else in just to confirm that the outlet itself works.

I tried using an Allen wrench to turn the motor from under the sink but no amount of my (admittedly weak) strength was able to get it to move. I can stick something down the sink and rotate both of the things freely, so I don't think there's anything stuck down there.

At this point I'm starting to think the unit just decided to die on me, but I'm not sure if there's something left I should try.

Comment: Do you have any sense of how old the unit is? Typical faults in old motor things: brushes, bearings, seals, switches. If it's fairly old, a new one is probably a good call. If it's pretty new and you have time/inclination, take it apart and look for anything obvious. You might get lucky.

Comment: Try inserting a broom stick into the disposal and try to pry the round plate connected to the motor..... this will give you more leverage that the Allen wrench.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate My best guess is that it's the original unit that came with the house in 2006, so plenty old.

Comment: @JACK are you saying from inside the sink? I was able to turn the two bottle cap type things with the butt end of a spatula, I'm not sure what else would be able to turn/move.

Comment: the whole bottom spins...

Comment: Yes, from inside the sink.

Comment: @JACK That did it, thank you so much. I'd read about using something to spin the plate but I just assumed it was talking about the other two things.

Comment: @Eabryt  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @eabryt, this site works on upvotes and choosing the answer that helped. I usually upvote the first helpful answer but in this case they were only a few minutes apart so they could be typing at the same time, upvote them both as I did then give the accepted green check mark to the best answer. This closes the question and others that may have the same problem can find it , thanks for using stack exchange DIY and tell your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inserting a broom stick into the disposal and try to pry the round plate connected to the motor..... this will give you more leverage that the Allen wrench.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the problem and / or age, attempting to rotate the drum is the very best way to get it working again.

If you let it "hum" long enough, it will trip the overload in the unit and you'd have to reset it. Kudos to you for not going that route.

Use a stout piece of wood, maybe like 3 ft long, like a plunger handle to move it. If that does not work after some exhausting efforts, either call a plumber or just replace it.

Comment: Gotta say I fully agree if you can’t break it loose trying both clock wise and counterclockwise with an Allen wrench a wood handle may be the only way remember to try both directions.+